# CS Cart - Showing thumbnail for configurable product options

Tags: cs-cart

I've just started using CS Cart and I have a product which has been built using the product configurator and I would like to show the image thumbnail next to each radio button.

What code do I need to use to pull the product thumbnail?

This is the current code I'm playing around with, but it is pulling the main image rather than the product image from the associated product in the configurator:

```
{include file="common_templates/image.tpl" images=$product.main_pair 
object_type="detailed_product" link_class="cm-thumbnails-mini cm-cur-item" 
image_width=$th_size image_height=$th_size show_thumbnail="Y" show_detailed_link=false 
make_box=true obj_id="`$product.product_id`_`$img_id`_mini" wrap_image=true}
```

P.S. I would have posted this on the CS Cart forums but can't seem to be able to register on there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$product is the main product. Find the variable that populates the products information (look for the code that generates the forms within the tabs.